# Execute PsExec from powershell within jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, psexec

When I execute `psexec \\<remote-machine> -u <user> -i 2 cmd.exe /c D:\temp_copy\run1.bat` from `powershell`, it executes. But when I try to execute the same from jenkins, it gives `The term '.\psexec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script...` . I injected the environment variables too which has the path of psexec, but still failed. Can someone guide me what I need to do.

Comment: You could either try to specify the full path to psexec or you dump the *path*  environment using `(gci env:Path | select -ExpandProperty Value) -split ';'`within your script to ensure the path is there.

Comment: It has the path of PSTools which contails psexec.exe

Comment: But when checked from jenkins its not present.

Comment: So the `Path` is probably not set for the system but for the user. I would specify the full path to psexec.

Comment: Now I get, The term '.\E:\PSTools\psexec.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...

Comment: you have to invoke it using `& 'E:\PSTools\psexec.exe' `

Comment: `The term 'E:\PSTools\psexec.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.At C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3078025387563077134.ps1:1 char:2`

Comment: If you get this error, the Path is invalid (you can test it using `Test-Path 'E:\PSTools\psexec.exe'`). Maybe the Jenkins Task runs on a different computer? You can also dump the whole environment using `gci env:` to check that.

Comment: First I modified the path variable using `$env:Path = $env:Path +  ";E:\PSTools;"` and then tested
`Test-Path 'E:\PSTools\psexec.exe'`. It returned `false`. But when dumping returns the path for psexec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110213/discussion-between-jisaak-and-imsirjayesh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I opened services.msc, Right Clicked on Jenkins-> Properties-> Log On tab-> Local System Account. Previously it was logged in with my username, so probably it didn't have access. Now its working fine.

Comment: Are you able to fix this? My Jenkins is on D drive and I am getting same error

Comment: I check the service, it is runnig using  Local System Account